# How to change the value in an array to a negative one

Tags: python, numpy

I converted an image to an array and I want to change those values to bipolar (1,-1) like this:

```
im = Image.open("letter_d.png").convert("L")
ar = np.array(im)
ar[ar == 0] = 1
ar[ar == 255] = -1
```

I get something like this:

```
[[255   1   1   1 255 255 255]
[  1   1   1   1   1 255 255]
[  1   1 255 255   1   1 255]
[  1   1 255 255 255   1   1]
[  1   1 255 255 255   1   1]
[  1   1 255 255 255   1   1]
[  1   1 255 255   1   1   1]
[  1   1   1   1   1   1 255]
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255]]
```

The problem is that the 255 values stay the same, I noticed that if instead I try to change them to a positive value like 2 it proceeds.

Comment: What datatype is your array (`ar.dtype`)?  If the datatype is `np.uint8`, then you _can't_ change them to a negative value without constructing an array of a different type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of dtype `uint8`:

```
>>> ar = np.array([0, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> ar
array([  0, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> ar[1] = -1
>>> ar
array([  0, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> ar[1] = -2
>>> ar
array([  0, 254], dtype=uint8)
```

If this is the case, you can't have negative values (the `u` in `uint8` means "unsigned").  When you try to set a negative value of `-1`, it "wraps around" to the maximum value (2's compliment).

You'll need to convert to a different (signed) type.

```
>>> signed_array = np.array(ar, dtype=int)
>>> signed_array
array([  0, 254])
>>> signed_array[1] = -1
>>> signed_array
array([ 0, -1])
```

The type you pick probably depends on what range of values you're going to be packing in there, but `int`/`np.int32` should be pretty safe for most applications...

Answer (score 0):

Converting the array to `np.int8` with `ar.astype(np.int8)` will automatically convert the `255`s to `-1`s